# Downloading files with Browser library

Tags: robotframework

I have been trying to download .xlsx or .pdf files with Robot framework while using Browser Library.
Every time browser downloads something the file name is just a bunch of random values.

> example: be3a051f-c533-4sac-b252-742d415b5e48

I have tried this keyword https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-browser/Browser.html#Download and just a basic "Click" on the file name but every time the file just gets saved as a example above, and the file doesn't include anything useful.
examples of the "code" used to click the file on browser

```
Click  text=${file_name}
Download   text=${file_name}
```

Is there something else i am missing which needs to be set to directly get the excel.xlsx file to download to a desired place?
I got "acceptDownloads" and "downloadsPath" set.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
${dl_promise}    Promise To Wait For Download    saveAs=D:\\Preview.zip
Click    //*[text()='Export CSV']
${file_obj}=    Wait For  ${dl_promise}
```